# How to get a sparse indicator matrix by a series lists of information?

Tags: python, pandas

I encountered a problem in create a sparse indicator matrix.

Let me describe my problem in brief.

Suppose I have
a list of categories:

```
cate = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

a matrix in each of whose row contains a subset of category:

```
mat = [["a","c"],["b"],["c","d","e"]]
```

I want to get
a sparse indicator matrix(could be a DataFrame):

```
result = [[1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1]]
```

If it could be derived by pandas operations, that could never be more cool!

Comment: Use `mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(mat),columns=mlb.classes_)`

Comment: If I want to do more based on the operation above, that is, I want to add order in it. For example, result = [[1,0,2,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,2,3]]. Could I handle this?